# HowTo empty a Vaadin 8.3.0 Chart?

Tags: vaadin8

i tried to empty a Vaadin 8 chart. I tried to overwrite it with an empty DataSeries. What am I doing wrong?

if i use:

```
    DataSeries emtpySeries = new DataSeries("");
    getUI().access(() -> junkPerMachineChart.setData(emtpySeries));
```

i get no error, but the chart is still there.

Comment: i found useful page. may my solution is in there: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/4550466/vaadin-chart-how-to-remove-all-dataseriesitem-from-a-series

Answer (score 0):

inspired by https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/4550466/vaadin-chart-how-to-remove-all-dataseriesitem-from-a-series
i found a solution how i could empty my chart named junkPerMachineChart.

```
private void emptyJunkPerMachineChart(){
    List<Series> s = new ArrayList<Series>();
    junkPerMachineChart.getConfiguration().setSeries(s);
    junkPerMachineChart.drawChart();
}
```